# Pandas - How to ignore a column when performing assert_frame_equal?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes with the same columns and content, however one of the columns `items` contains a list of lists and, although they match in both dataframes, `assert_frame_equal` returns false and says they are not.

Is there a way to bypass this or not have it compare this column in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I can't reproduce your problem with Pandas 1.4.1, here is one way to exclude columns from equality comparison:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3],
        "items": [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3],
        "items": [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 10]],
    }
)

assert_frame_equal(df1.drop(columns=["items"]), df2.drop(columns=["items"]))
# No AssertionError exception raised
```

Comment: Thanks Laurent, seems the only way really!